# Answers parameter not functional

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers

For example the following:

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions?answers=true

doesn't return answers.

Comment: 'strue.  Finding the same thing.

Comment: `/questions` used to **never** return answers, thus the confusion.  In the next code push it will gain support for the `answers` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed.

[Example](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions?answers=true)